# Convert dictionary with coordinates and values to 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

Assume the next dictionary is given:

```
{(0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 12, (2, 2): 802, (3, 3): 1687, (4, 4): 11, (5, 4): 4, (6, 5): 593, (7, 4): 4}
```

In the dictionary above each key displays a point in the matrix `(x, y)` and a value displays the value found in the matrix. How could I construct an array that will contain the values located at each point `x`, `y`?

According to the dictionary above the expected result is:

```
array([[   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,   12,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,  802,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0, 1687,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,   11,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  593],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0]])
```

Comment: Do you know the size of the array in advance? Do you initialize it to zeros?

Comment: It can be assumed that the size of the matrix is known in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html), defining the shape of the array beforehand from the keys:

```
d = {(0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 12, (2, 2): 802, (3, 3): 1687, (4, 4): 11, 
     (5, 4): 4, (6, 5): 593, (7, 4): 4}

i,j = zip(*d.keys())
a = np.zeros((max(i)+1,max(j)+1), np.int32)
np.add.at(a, tuple((i,j)), tuple(d.values()))

a
array([[   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,   12,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,  802,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0, 1687,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,   11,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  593],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0]])
```

Comment: I'm wondering if it's safe to assume `d.keys()` and `d.values()` will necessarily be in the same order if they're not called in the same line, as `dict` isn't inherently ordered.  I suppose it's probably fine as long as the `dict` isn't being  accessed by another process.

Comment: Maybe to be safe do `np.add.at(a, tuple(zip(*d.keys())), tuple(d.values()))`?

Comment: Why is it safer @DanielF ? The generator has already been unpacked. SHould be the asme

Comment: Isn't it unpacked twice though here?  It probably is fine, I've just been burned so many times by assuming `python` dictionaries are ordered that I'm probably over-cautious.

Comment: One thing is that they might not maintain insertion order. But successive calls to `.values()` and `.keys()` are consistent @DanielF

Comment: Ahh, ok, that's new-ish.  Came up scripting in 2.7 so I still have those habits.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [coo](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) sparse matrix and convert to array afterwards:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

data= {(0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 12, (2, 2): 802, (3, 3): 1687, (4, 4): 11, (5, 4): 4, (6, 5): 593, (7, 4): 4}

row, col, fill = zip(*[(*k, v) for k, v in data.items()])

result = coo_matrix((fill, (row, col)), shape=(8, 6)).toarray()
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[   1    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0   12    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0  802    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0 1687    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0   11    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    4    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0  593]
 [   0    0    0    0    4    0]]
```

Comment: Or just `coo_matrix((tuple(data.values()), tuple(zip(*data.keys())))).toarray()`.  But I think `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix` is a bit less messy.

Answer (score 1):

My 2cents:

```
n=np.zeros([max(d.keys(), key=lambda x:x[0])[0]+1,max(d.keys(), key=lambda x:x[1])[1]+1], int)

for i,k in d.items():
    n[i[0], i[1]]=k

>>>print(n)

array([[   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,   12,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,  802,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0, 1687,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,   11,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  593],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just a dictionary of keys (`dok`) representation for sparse matrices.  So . . .

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

out = dok_matrix((8, 8), dtype = int)
out._update(d)
out.todense()

Out[]: 
matrix([[   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,   12,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,  802,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0, 1687,    0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0,   11,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  593,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0,    0,    0]])
```

Comment: Well that's a new class to me... nice!

Comment: yeah, unfortunately the package creators changed the `.update()` functionality a few years ago to not accept `dict` input unless you use the mangled version, so it's kind of hidden.

Comment: ref, since it's important *why* this was done:  https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8338

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way of extracting values of any iterable in pure numpy is `np.fromiter`. And here is a good occasion to use it:

**Approach 1**

```
d = {(0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 12, (2, 2): 802, (3, 3): 1687, (4, 4): 11, (5, 4): 4, (6, 5): 593, (7, 4): 4}
X = np.zeros((8,8), dtype=int)
idx = np.fromiter(d, dtype='i,i').view(int).reshape(-1, 2)
vals = np.fromiter(d.values(), dtype=float)
X[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]] = vals
```

*Remark:* I mean extracting values of iterable that corresponds to some shape. `itertools.chain` is needed in addition otherwise.

**Approach 2**

`itertools.chain` is a very fast way to flatten iterables which gives a significant boost to `np.fromiter`. It has no requirements for sizes of iterable items. This works 2.5x times faster than previous alternative:

```
import itertools
X = np.zeros((8,8), dtype=int)
idx = np.fromiter(itertools.chain(*d.keys()), dtype=int).reshape(-1,2)
vals = np.fromiter(d.values(), dtype=float)
X[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]] = vals
```

**Approach 3**

`zip` could be used instead of `itertools.chain` but it still little bit (5-10%) slower than approach 2:

```
X = np.zeros((8,8), dtype=int)
idx1, idx2 = zip(*d.keys())
vals = np.fromiter(d.values(), dtype=float)
X[idx1, idx2] = vals
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array size is known already, you can do this,

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((8, 6), dtype='int')
d = {(0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 12, (2, 2): 802, (3, 3): 1687, (4, 4): 11, (5, 4): 4, (6, 5): 593, (7, 4): 4}

for key, val in d.items():
    arr[key[0]][key[1]] = val
    
array([[   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
   [   0,   12,    0,    0,    0,    0],
   [   0,    0,  802,    0,    0,    0],
   [   0,    0,    0, 1687,    0,    0],
   [   0,    0,    0,    0,   11,    0],
   [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0],
   [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  593],
   [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import numpy as np

    cols = max(key[0] for key in d) + 1
    rows = max(key[1] for key in d) + 1

    mat = np.zeros((cols, rows), dtype=np.int)
    for point in d: mat[point] = d[point]

    print(mat)

####### result #######
[[   1    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0   12    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0  802    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0 1687    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0   11    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    4    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0  593]
 [   0    0    0    0    4    0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution is:

```
import numpy as np

d = {(0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 12, (2, 2): 802, (3, 3): 1687, (4, 4): 11, (5, 4): 4, (6, 5): 593, (7, 4): 4}

X = np.zeros((8,8))
X[tuple(np.array(list(d.keys())).T)] = list(d.values())
```

Which output:

```
array([[   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,   12,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,  802,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0, 1687,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,   11,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  593,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    4,    0,    0,    0]], dtype=uint32)
```

Use tuple of `numpy` arrays which can be directly passed to the matrix to get the elements and then assign the values of the dictionary.

Comment: `np.array(list(...))` is easy to read but slower than `np.fromiter`

Comment: @mathfux you are right, thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.zeros((8,6))
your_dict = {(0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 12, (2, 2): 802, (3, 3): 1687, (4, 4): 11, (5,4): 4, (6, 5): 593, (7, 4): 4}
for key, value in your_dict.items():
    matrix[key[0],key[1]] = value
```

In case your matrix is other size consider changing the zeros initialization

Output

```
[[   1    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0   12    0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0  802    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0 1687    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0   11    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    4    0]
 [   0    0    0    0    0  593]
 [   0    0    0    0    4    0]]
```